# ul adding additional class which is not used anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on ul with javascript/jquery and I'm facing a very strange issue. It was working fine before I worked  with some tags and, after that, it is creating an issue: it is adding an additional class "ui-selectable" which is not used anywhere in the whole code and it is messing with the functionality of the code.

See the code below

```
 <div class="row"><ul id="selectMe" class="selectMe1">

  <li class="myList">Monday</li>

  <li class="myList">Tuesday</li>

  <li class="myList">Wednesday</li>

  <li class="myList">Thursday</li>

  <li class="myList">Friday</li>

  <li class="myList">Saturday</li>

  <li class="myList">Sunday</li>
```

The url of the project is [here](http://matterforall.com/index.php?mod=new_listing&package=2) see at the end on business hours
here is the screen shot [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKZa3.png)

Comment: What is the question?? Please post your code here, not links

Comment: it is adding an additional class "ui-selectable" which is not used anywhere in the whole code and it is messing with the functionality of the code.i dont know why it is comming

Comment: Are you using ui-selectable from jquery ui with id SelectMe?

Comment: What is? You haven't shown any code so how can we help??

Comment: @groomy no i am not using ui-selectable it is adding automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find jQuery UI method **selectable()** in your code and remove that method.
Alternatively you can remove particular class like below:

```
jQuery('ul#selectMe').removeClass('ui-selectable');
```

(EDIT)

I found script in your page source:

```
$(function(){
  $("#selectMe").selectable();
  });
```

Just remove that script if you are not using.

Comment: thanks bro it was clashing with the same id on some other project resource thanks for pointing out the issue,Thumbs Up

Answer (score 0):

if You are using **Jquery-UI** or any other framework then this class is coming from that way But if you are thinking this is additional and should not be part of *ul class* then You can remove the class with Jquery:

```
$('ul#selectMe').removeClass('ui-selectable');
```

Comment: did you put it in the main body of jquery? as $(document).ready(function(){  });

Comment: try with a developer tool of chrome or firefox